# pandas query only showing true values while grouped

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I got the following DataFrame:

```
column1  |  column2
1        | dasd
2        | dasd
1        | 
2        | foo
1        | dasd
2        | bar
```

I want to group the entry by column1 and only get a list of entries which have more than one unique entry in column2.

So I got this:

```
df.groupby("column1")["column2"].nunique() > 1
```

which gives me the following:

```
column1
1 False
2 True
```

How do I get a series or list with only the entries in column1 that are True.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can filtering `index` values by boolean `Series`:

```
s = df.groupby("column1")["column2"].nunique() > 1
out = s.index[s].tolist()
print (out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with the following:

```
df1 = df.groupby(by="column1", as_index=False).agg({"column2: pd.Series.nunique})
df1[df1.column2 > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In other words your question breaks down to groupby both column1 and column2

```
>>> df.groupby(['column1','column2']).size() > 1

     column1  column2
1             False
      dasd     True
2     bar     False
      dasd    False
      foo     False
```